# JQuery mobile page div margin changes during transition. How can I prevent it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, cordova

Currently Im creating a phonegap app using jquery mobile and I faced this problem. When manually give a margin-bottom to the data-role='page' div, the margin disappears during the transition and comes back in when the transition is done. I want to keep the margin during the transition too. Please help me out. This is my HTML code:

```
<body>

    <div id='show-back' onclick='goBack();' style='display:none'><div class='back-button'></div></div>

    <div id='show-logout' style='display:none' onclick='clickLogout();'><div class='logout-button'></div></div>

    <div class='all-area'>

        <div class='header-area'>

            <div class='header-logo'><img src='img/unic-logo.gif' alt='' style='margin-top:20px' /></div>

        </div>

        <div class='content-area'>

            <div class='content-wrapper'>

                <div data-role='page' style='margin-bottom:150px !important;' id='home-page' data-title='University of Nicosia' data-theme='a'>


  AREA WHERE THE PAGES TRANSIT....

                </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>

        <div class='menu-area'>

            <div class='menu-icon-wrapper'>
                <a href='social.html' data-transition='none'><div class='menu-settings'>Settings</div></a>
                <a href='social.html' data-transition='none'><div class='menu-global'>Website</div></a>
                <a href='social.html' data-transition='none'><div class='menu-chat'>Social Networks</div></a>
                <a href='social.html' data-transition='none'><div class='menu-refresh'>Feedback</div></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you notice on the data-role='page' div I included the style definition specifying bottom margin.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I just had to make another div with bottom margin inside the data-role='page' div rather than giving bottom margin directly. Then I had to fix the div height using jquery. Here is the code:

```
<div data-role='page' id='home-page' data-title='University of Nicosia' data-theme='a'>
  <div style='margin-bottom:150px;position:relative;width:100%;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden' id='content-fixer'>

   AREA WHERE THE PAGES TRANSIT....
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(docment).ready(function() {

    var contentHeight = $('#home-page').height();
    $('#content-fixer').height(contentHeight-150);
  });

</script>
```